# Simple JSON request to Update Database row from Razor Page and return success/failure

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, razor-pages, razor-2

I've tried every example I could find but they are all too complex for my simple need. I haven't needed json until now, so I am kinda cross eyed.

I have the need for a button that calls a Razor Page code behind using JSON and updates a field in a database with today's date.
Essentially, the user wants to print a "Final Approval Letter" (this works) but also push a button (for now) that updates the course's field "FinalApprovalDate" to Today().

I can do the database update and determine success/failure in a normal Razor Page code behind. But a JSON call with no page reload seems a lot more elegant. It is the JSON that has me stumped. Hopefully my suffering will help someone else in the future. No lists are needed, no classes, just a request and response with most of the action being the database update. (which I have left out for the purpose of focusing on my JSON stupidity).

---

### In Startup.cs right before services.AddMVC()

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
services.AddSession();
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

---

### At top of FinalApprovalLetter.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function updateRow () {
        $.get('/FinalApprovalLetter/').done(function () {

                $('#success').append([message returned from JsonResult OnGet]);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

### In body of FinalApprovalLetter.cshtml: Button to update database/row

```
    <input type="button" class="d-print-none" value="Set Final Date For Course (today)" onclick="updateRow" />
   <br />
    <label id="success" />
```

---

### In code behind FinalApprovalLetter.chstml.cs

```
public JsonResult OnGet()
{
  //DO database row update, insert today's date in FinalApprovalDate field
  //DETERMINE AND RETURN SUCCESS/FAILURE (records affected)
  //I HAVE CODE TO DO THIS AND IT WILL WORK 

    return new JsonResult("[success/failure message");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Today it's recommended to use the native [`JSON.Parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method to parse the JSON.

So you could do this in `OnGet()`, adding whatever other fields to the return object:

```
public JsonResult OnGet()
{
  //DO database row update, insert today's date in FinalApprovalDate field
  //DETERMINE AND RETURN SUCCESS/FAILURE (records affected)
  //I HAVE CODE TO DO THIS AND IT WILL WORK 

    return JsonResult(new { success = "message text" });
}
```

Then parse the JSON returned and use the value. Make sure that the JQuery library is included whether through a common page or through this page, or this code will error out about JQuery not being included.

The section that defines `updateRow` needs to have executed before the `onclick` handler is invoked or there will be an error.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateRow () {
        $.get('/FinalApprovalLetter/').done(function (data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#success').append(obj.success);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks bcr! I get the "Json" underlined in red in the code behind return: "return Json(new { success = "message text" });" and it says when I mouse over. "The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context". I don't recognize any of the potential fixes like I normally do. Any ideas? I am very grateful disciple.

Comment: is `OnGet()` an API controller method?

Comment: No, I am using Razor Pages. I was able to add this with no red line:
" return new JsonResult(new { success = "message text" });" . . . However, now I get the error: "System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple handlers matched." I think my JSON OnGet() is conflicting with my Razor Page's  OnGetAsync(). Both are handlers I guess and it ok's the first. Maybe I am not calling the correct Json task.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty confusing at this point,only seeing part of your code. I assume that error means it's finding multiple handlers for the same route of `/FinalApprovalLetter/`

Comment: You need a named handler to disambiguate the OnGet methods: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods#named-handler-methods

Comment: Ok, I changed OnGet() to OnPost(), no more "2 handler" error. However, looking in Chrome developer tools because button doesn' fire function updateRows() it says:

"ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at FinalApprovalLetter?id=3973:209" and 2nd javacript error: "ReferenceError: updateRow is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (FinalApprovalLetter?id=3973:52)"

I don't think my jquery is working, all the libraries and references exist. I tried putting the function in a $document ready:   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(function updateRow() {

Comment: @bcr, pretty much what I have posted is all my code. Nothing fancy, just a post or get to already existing page that runs an update query. Heck, I could even avoid the returned status message. Just a call to the code behind where I run an update ADO query. right now I can't seem to get the button onclick to call the json function in the client code.

Comment: Worse comes to worse I can just call another Razor Page that does the update and then redirects to the current one. That is 2 page loads, kinda clunky, client won't care but this simple problem I think would be very useful for the community that is just getting used to Razor Pages Core .NET 2.2.

Comment: @JustJohn yeah there’s a scoping problem with the JS. Will update shortly with what may help.